# How to display image in text box in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have this code

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For Each c As String In TextBox2.Text

sb.AppendFormat("<img src='{0}.jpg'/>", c)
sb.AppendLine(Line)

 Next
    Textbox3.Text = sb.ToString()
```

Suppose i get image inside my textbox3 but it didn't execute. It just come out the url of the image. how I'm going to get it. I had used literal.text but my image doesn't execute line by line i want my image execute like image below

[image]

Comment: Why do you think putting an `img` tag in a text box would show the image? A "text box" is exactly that: A box for showing and editing *text*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a WebBrowser control to display your images:

```
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For Each c As String In Me.TextBox1.Text
        sb.AppendFormat("<img src='{0}.jpg'/>", c)
    Next

    Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = sb.ToString
```

This is a simple code to start your project.

To obtain the same result in your image I think you also had to:

- declare a better HTML and pass it to WebBrowser.DocumentText
- use a multiline textbox and handle the carriage return

Answer (score 0):

if you want the same effect, you could take a vertical slice of your composite image, set it as the css background-image of the textbox, with background-repeat:repeat